# Scala: trying to understand Traits, 'abstract override' and stacking

Tags: scala, traits

Assuming I have a simple abstract base class like so:

```
abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass { 
    def hello : Unit 
}
```

and then I write a "stacking" trait like so:

```
trait MyTrait extends MyAbstractBaseClass { 
    abstract override def hello : Unit = 
    { 
        super.hello             
        println("How are you?"); 
    }
}
```

then why won't Scala let me define a subclass as follows:

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractBaseClass with MyTrait {
    override def hello : Unit = println("Hello!")
}

error: overriding method hello in trait MyTrait of type => Unit;
 method hello needs `abstract override' modifiers
```

If I try their suggestion of using 'abstract override':

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractBaseClass with MyTrait {
    abstract override def hello : Unit = println("Hello!")
}

error: `abstract override' modifier only allowed for members of traits
```

Can anyone help me understand this?

P.S. I know that the below does work:

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractBaseClass {
   override def hello : Unit = println("Hello!")
}

val x = new MyClass with MyTrait
x.hello

Hello!
How are you?
```

but am trying to understand why the former does not.

**In summary**: why can't I provide an implementation of the abstract base class - while also taking advantage of the trait's functionality?

Comment: "`abstract override' modifier only allowed for members of traits" + "error: `abstract override' modifier only allowed for members of traits" = you can't override abstractly overriden methods inside a class

Comment: Thanks @dk14, it makes sense to me that I can't use 'abstract override'.  What I don't understand is why I can't provide an implementation of the abstract base class - while also taking advantage of the trait's functionality?

Comment: What if you remove the `override` keyword in your `MyClass` definition (in your block number 3 on the post). You can't override (from MyClass) a trait's method that is marked abstract override. The last block is valid since  your stackable stack with traits is made after a valid compilation of `MyClass`.

Comment: @Mik378: then I get error: overriding method hello in trait MyTrait of type => Unit;
 method hello needs `override' modifier

Comment: Can you post the code you changed here?

Comment: @Mik378
class MyClass extends MyAbstractBaseClass with MyTrait {
    def hello = println("Hello!")
 }//i.e. just removed the 'override' keyword

Answer (score 2):

**The trick is that you can't have an "abstract" method in the flow of the linearization, that is called from a `super` call.**

Try this, you will see it compiles:

```
abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass {
  def hello : Unit
}

class SubClass extends MyAbstractBaseClass {
  def hello {
    println("toto")
  }
}


trait MyTrait extends MyAbstractBaseClass {
  abstract override def hello : Unit =
  {
    super.hello
    println("How are you?")
  }
}

class MyClass extends SubClass with MyTrait {  //note the CONCRETE SubClass here
  override def hello : Unit = println("Hello!")
}

new MyClass().hello
```

You got the error, because the compiler starts with `MyTrait` (at the top of the stack, so the first to be called) and that `MyTrait` calls through `super` an abstract method... (of `MyAbstractBaseClass`) => it crashes since your `super` call can't target immediately a concrete method.

In my code snippet, you will notice that `MyTrait` is "at the top" (during linearization) of a **concrete** `Subclass` class, that makes the trick.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply.  Just so I'm sure I've understood it correctly: in my example I've set up the stack in the wrong order (MyAbstractBaseClass <- MyTrait <- MyClass).  What yours does is put it in the right order (MyAbstractBaseClass <- SubClass <- MyTrait).  Have I understood correctly?

Comment: No. At linearization time, order of `hello` calls would be:  `MyTrait` -> `MyAbstractBaseClass`  -> `MyClass`. Thus, `MyTrait`'s `hello` method would call `MyAbstractBaseClass`'s `hello` method ... but non-concrete method ! So it does not compile.  In My example, it would call `SubClass`, that IS a concrete class with a **non-abstract** `hello` method.

Comment: Note that in your second example, that works: `val x = new MyClass with MyTrait
x.hello`, you mix `MyTrait` with a CONCRETE class called `MyClass`, so as explained, this works.

Comment: I've just tried making MyAbstractBaseClass a concrete class (including an implementation for 'hello').  If I do this, my original code compiles, and the order of hello calls is MyClass, MyTrait and then MyAbstractBaseClass.  Not MyTrait, MyAbstractBaseClass and then MyClass.

Comment: Code:
class A { def hello = println("A") }; 
trait B extends A { abstract override def hello = { println("B"); super.hello }};
class C extends A with B { override def hello = { println("C"); super.hello }};
(new C).hello;